# Determining the language by the path of Url

Tags: next.js, react-i18next, next-i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

I tried to find a way to change the language by changing the site's sub-path in the next-i18next package, I searched the Internet (https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/32 , https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector#detector-options) for an answer to this question, but it did not work. After changing the subpath in the url it is duplicated and redirects me to a page that does not exist.

[image]

my code:

```js
// path-to-my-project/i18n.js
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default;
const i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector = require('i18next-browser-languagedetector').default;
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
    otherLanguages: ['ru'],
    defaultNS: 'common',
    localeSubpaths,
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
    use: [i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector],
});
```

```js
// path-to-my-project/pages/_app.js
import '../styles/main.scss';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
import Router from 'next/router';
import App from 'next/app';
import { appWithTranslation } from '../i18n';

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
);

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => ({ ...await App.getInitialProps(appContext) });

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

maybe I just missed something, because it's my first project on next.js, so I'm asking for help in the community and would be grateful for any help or hint.

Answer (score 2):

By default `next-i18next` will try to detect the language to show from [users browser](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/master/src/config/default-config.ts#L25).

Try to disable it.

```js
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig
const path = require('path')

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  browserLanguageDetection: false, // <---
  serverLanguageDetection: false, // <---
  otherLanguages: ['de'],
  localeSubpaths,
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales')
})
```

Comment: but now when changing the language via url, the server returns 404

Comment: that is, when changing English to Russian everything works, but when changing Russian to English 404 is returned, and with the help of the button for changing the language everything works.

Answer (score 1):

in file next.config.js i have this settings:

```
// path/to/project/next.config.js

const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites');

const localeSubpaths = {
    ru: 'ru',
};

module.exports = {
    rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        localeSubpaths,
    },
    devIndicators: {
        autoPrerender: false,
    },
};
```

but there was not enough configuration for English localization, so you just need to add it:

```
// path/to/project/next.config.js

const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites');

const localeSubpaths = {
    en: 'en', // <------
    ru: 'ru',
};

module.exports = {
    rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        localeSubpaths,
    },
    devIndicators: {
        autoPrerender: false,
    },
};
```